# About spacing between three identical symbols

Tags: spacing

The following code

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
 $*,**,***$
 \end{document}
```

---

yields

[image]

What can be done in order to get rid of the different spacing when three consecutive identical symbols are used? (I only experienced this issue with the asterisk; maybe this behavior is exclusive of this symbol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that TeX interprets the middle `*` as a binary operator in `***`, so it adds more space. With one or two `*`'s this does not happen because binary operators need two operands.

To turn this "feature" off use `{*}`, which tells TeX to interpret the `*` as an ordinary character.

Changing your MWE to:

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \begin{document}
   $*,**,*{*}*$
   \end{document}
```

gives the output:

[image]

Comment: +1, although it's a feature, not a "feature" `;-P`